# How n where should I start learning Java?

Tags: java

From where should I start java?
Which book should I prefer?

Comment: Hi Sahil Tiwaskar, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).

Comment: Why java? Why, oh, why?

Answer (score 1):

In spite of their insulting titles, I’ve always found the *… for Dummies* books to be clear and well-written, with a logical progression in their respective subjects, building later information on a foundation of the earlier information. You might be able to find better; you can certainly find worse.